# Why won't apache pass my cURL request through to php when I have brackets [ ] in the data?

Tags: php, json, curl, zend-framework

I am trying to test a JSON RPC implementation by posting from curl. The json roc spec requires the params to be an array, using brackets. The following post never gets to php. It seems that apache is catching it.

```
curl <url> -i -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" --data '{"method" : "validateSubdomain", "params" : ["test"]}'
```

I get the following response:

> HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
>
> Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 21:21:42 GMT
>
> Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.3.8-ZS5.5.0 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8-ZS5.5.0 ZendServer/5.0
>
> Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
>
> Content-Length: 80
>
> Content-Type: text/html

If i drop the brackets, I get errors from my php application which means it is passing it through. It is only when I have those brackets in there that I get the 204 response.

I am running ZendServer/apache. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: I just found that it is specifically the combination of the "params" key with the array brackets. If I do something like "parameters" : ["data"] then it is fine. JSON RPC wants "params" though.

Comment: This sounds like a processing logic problem. Show your code. (And Apaches `mod_security` is unlikely to filter that specific pair of values, and would bail with another error anyway.)

Comment: I have tried echoing anything in the very beginning of my index.php bootstrap file and it doesn't even get there. It definitely seems that apache isn't directing the request correctly, but only with the "params" and bracket combination.

Comment: I didn't find out why the problem is happening, but the JSON RPC spec defines an id to be passed as well. If I pass an id in after, then it works fine. No idea why still so if you have any input, I'm still interested to hear it.

Comment: Have no code to debug this; and it's certainly not a common issue. You should just test it with another server, e.g. `php -S` or so.

Comment: You get an X-Powered-By php header; doesn't that imply apache has passed the data to PHP, and it is PHP that is crashing on the parsing stage (given that it doesn't reach the first line of index.php). Edit php.ini to show all errors (including start-up errors), and see if you get anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running from Windows cmd then the call should look like this,

```
curl -X POST --data "{\"method\":\"makePayment\",\"params\":{\"recipient\":\"Penny Adams\",\"amount\":175.05},\"id\":\"0001\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}" <url>
```

Jsons params work in named pairs also Zend wants all the info method, id and json version.

Things ive noticed is that in win cmd you have to escape all the " that is inside the --data"" else it gets read in pieces